# Horror Movie, video game, 2 adults one child maybe girl leave

Tags: story-identification, video-games, horror

I came across this page on accident. It might finally solve my quest for a movie that has been on my mind for roughly 10 years I would guess.

I was extremely young when I watched this, so bear in mind details are patchy.

It was around Christmas time, maybe New Year's, and I had the night perfectly planned; first I would watch the Buzz Lightyear movie, and I had timed it perfectly so after it finished *Star Wars: The Phantom Menace* would turn on, then a movie that, when I read about it in the TV Guide (I'm from Australia by the way), sounded amazing and I was hooked before I had even seen it.

From memory this is what I know:

- A group of people, male and female enter a building.
- A nerd, I think, in the group said it was like a video game he played.
- Inside the building they start dying, one by one. The nerd, from what I remember, dies because he thinks he can "cheat" by going towards what I think was an elevator and there was possibly an orb he put his head into. Either the doors or the orb cut his head off.
- In the end, if I am not mistaken, a male and female adult exit the building from a pipe with a little girl or boy into a "new day." At the end of the pipe or tunnel is an extremely bright light.

Comment: My first impulse is *Stay Alive* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_Alive), but the details don't match, and 2006 is probably way too recent.

Comment: My first guess is 1997's [*The Cube.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/)

Comment: Neither ring a bell unfortunately after having a look.

Comment: "Two adults enter... one child leaves." It's obviously Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be extremely similar to another, [more recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/gruesome-scifi-horror-b-movie-1990s-2000s-similar-premise-to-the-cube-except-i), which has an accepted answer of the 2013 film "Subterano." See that question's answer for a video excerpt that may jog your memory.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long shot, but your description sounds a bit like [*The Cube,*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/) released in 1997. IIRC it has most of the points you remember, although the "boy" is an autistic adult. [This Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_%28film%29) has a pretty complete description.

Comment: Hey Joe, I am about to watch The Cube, more or less anyway at this stage, will skip some bits to see if it is what I remember.

Comment: Watching glances of it and the ending it doesn't seem familiar at all unfortunately. The ending I remember is that the 3 people exit it together, as if they were to become a family as it ended