# Gruesome scifi horror B-Movie 1990s-2000s, similar premise to The Cube, except in a car park?

Tags: story-identification, horror

Here's what I remember:-

- A group of heroes and not heroes try to escape a tiered dungeon sort of thing, working their way up. The casualties mount until there's only a girl, and a love interest left.
- It's pretty much a converted car park.
- A character gets his head taken off by some spherical device he sticks it into. I believe he got to communicate with the guy running the dungeon through it, somehow.
- Another character, somehow isolated from the rest of the gang, falls into some sort of steel wire trap; the sudden tightening of the wire (or something) removes his body from his feet. He offers money from his wallet before dying somehow or rather.
- The "main heroes" who survive at the end exit the dungeon thing with the sun in their eyes, as majestic silhouettes.
- The love interest somehow remove the girl from some electrocution torture thing she's strapped to.
- I think it was produced by Showtime Australia... maybe. Either they've since disowned it, or my memory is wrong – I couldn't find it through that link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Subterano](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0255623/)* from 2003

[image]

> Eleven souls, trapped in an underground carpark, are attacked by deadly, remote controlled toys. Only a few will survive.

**Trailer**

It was filmed and released in Australia. According to *[Australian Horror films 1973-2010](https://books.google.com/books?id=rsOSKIVbGUQC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=subterano%20showtime&source=bl&ots=LM6esZSrhE&sig=LAquaUqsswnOQ7owJLibRF29yqs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNkcTN-qvKAhWHESwKHfbtBDAQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=subterano%20showtime&f=false)*, it was released by Showtime Australia. They also have a plot summary for the entire movie:

> Some time in a future world, Conrad is an assassin for the group "Orphans for the Revolution." He escapes from the vehicle that was transporting him to his execution. He finds his former girlfriend, Grace Stone, who frives him to the Embo Industries car park (parking garage), "Safe Park." The car park is closed for the night, and Conrad, Grace, and a group of feral children are locked inside with Sheriff. They are challenged to play a game with Emboman. People are killed one by one by Emboman's toys. His virtual reality figure is defeated by Conrad, who discovers he has a son by Grace, named Jake. Conrad, Jake, and Grace exit the car park through the sewers and head to the mountains. Emboman is revealed to be Todd, the son of Cunningham, the president of Embo Industries.

There are more details further down in the book entry discussing the death via orb, the feet being cut off, and the electric torture.

Comment: Ta! What an awful, awful film :-)