# 90's Sci-Fi Horror action movie with antagonist in suit with umbilical cord

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

An American (I think) 90's Sci-Fiction Horror action movie set in a dystopian world where a group of strangers have to group up and work to together to survive are led by some ex cop/military man who is the protagonist.

They try to survive against various traps and killer robots. He and the survivors try to escape from some underground facility or a huge underground car parking lot.

The main Antagonist is some rich sadistic blond kid that has this suit in which he connects with an umbilical cord and can control (from his house/mansion) small killer robots and traps like the box trap that decapitate one of the survivors and some weird wire trap that almost kills a girl near the end.

There was also this crazy (redhead?) woman that goes berserk and becomes the secondary antagonist. There could also be a terminator like robot but my memory is a bit foggy at this point.

Eventually the remaining survivors escape through a tunnel/hole into the outside world and when the blonde kid tries to remove the suit, the cable connected to his umbilical cord remains stuck and the movie ends.

I saw this strange Sci-Fi Horror Action movie during the 90's on TV and always wondered what it was called. For a long time now I've thought that the blonde kid was Ryan Phillippe so I recently decided to check it out but couldn't find the movie in his IMDb page; so it's probably someone who looks similar to him or my memory is just bad.

Real curious if someone saw this flick besides me and knows the actual title.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/gruesome-scifi-horror-b-movie-1990s-2000s-similar-premise-to-the-cube-except-i

Answer (score 8):

Could it be "Subterano"(2003)?

It takes place in an underground car park, has a blonde kid in a suit with a cord which helps him control deadly machines, and he strongly resembles Ryan Phillipe.
Here is the IMDb page.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0255623/

And here is a short trailer where you can see the suit with the cord, the deadly toys and the red headed woman.