# Movie with a monster made from balls/spheres

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching this movie somewhere around the 2000s (2000-2003 I think).

There was a humanoid monster looking like some kind of robot, made from white/silver balls or spheres. It moved between places, turning into some kind of fluid mess of these balls. There was also a person, who stuck his head into a hole in a wall and it (his head) was cut.

The surroundings in the movie, if I remember correctly, looked like sci-fi. It's not *Phantasm*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything about any other characters in the films, such as the protagonist/s? Also, do you have any sense of how old the movie was when you watched it?

Comment: Was the ball-robot CGI or some kind of practical effect?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember anything about other characters.
Only the moment when the man's head was cut in the hole.

As for robot, fluid of these balls was CGI.
Don't remember the robot itself :(

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Even though it's not Phantasm, that's not an excuse to not watch Phantasm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Subterano](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0255623/)* (2003) as per the answer to [Gruesome scifi horror B-Movie 1990s-2000s, similar premise to The Cube, except in a car park?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/gruesome-scifi-horror-b-movie-1990s-2000s-similar-premise-to-the-cube-except-i)

> Eleven souls, trapped in an underground carpark, are attacked by deadly, remote controlled toys. Only a few will survive.

In the linked question/answer, you see a mention of the fellow getting his head cut off while he's got it stuck inside the "communication sphere".

### Trailer (robot of spheres at 0:50)

Comment: This is actually it :D
Jeez, my memory is very hazy about this movie, I can hardly call it "sci-fi" surroundings .
Thanks!

Comment: @helge6path: Glad to help! Your question has been closed as a Duplicate, but that's not a censure, or saying it's a bad question. This is just how we tie common answers together. You will still get points for upvotes.